# One-way / One-time data binding in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

While it is not really a performance issue with my very small and very quick application, I am interested in becoming proficient in dealing with large applications BEFORE I get to working on large applications.  This is causing me to identify ways to optimize AngularJS in as many ways as possible, and to integrate these optimizations as part of my "normal" coding routine.  So!  I've been scratching my head for several hours now, scouring articles and the documentation, trying to get ahold of the best method for me to achieve the following:

1. I have a drop-down select menu with options that I would like to be one-way data bound, from view to model, as there is no need to have the model update the view in this case.

Some questions about the above:
Will this save me time in the $digest cycle?  Or does it not matter if I just use the two-way data binding of ng-model?

My other question is a little more involved.

2. **EDIT:** This issue has been fixed (as seen below), but I am now encountering a new issue.  I have posted this new issue to the bottom of this question for better visibility.

Here is my template:

**DropdownTemplate.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="{{::regarding}}" class="col-sm-12 control-label">{{::regarding}}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <select class="form-control" id="{{::regarding}}" data-ng-model="data" data-ng-change="update()">
            <option selected>0</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>12</option>
            <option>13</option>
            <option>14</option>
            <option>15</option>
            <option>16</option>
            <option>17</option>
            <option>18</option>
            <option>19</option>
            <option>20</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my directive:

```
.directive('trDropdown', ['Ticket', function(Ticket) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'DropdownTemplate.html',
        scope: {
            regarding: '@'
        },
        link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs){
            $scope.data = 0;
            $scope.update = function (){
                Ticket[$scope.regarding] = $scope.data;
                //console.log(Ticket[$scope.regarding]);
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

And here is what it looks like when I utilize this custom element in my main html page:

```
<tr-dropdown regarding="Adults"></tr-dropdown>
```

So far, my code runs the way it should, except for one small bug.  The bug is that, if I don't include the bit about $scope.data = 0; in the link part of the directive, the attribute "selected" (or even selected="selected") doesn't register when my custom element is appended to the main html page. Despite the bug (which is not my primary concern), I don't feel like this is the most elegant way for me to handle the concept of one-way binding, if I even need it at all.  I know that there is a plugin called **bindonce** that I am willing to use, although I have been searching first for a native solution.

Any discoveries found through the struggles of others is most welcome on this end!

**EDIT: One-time binding is now successfully working but I've encountered a strange anomaly.  Batarang shows my expression {{::regarding}} as continuing to pull resources, each time one of the dropdowns is changed.  As far as I understand, {{::regarding}} should be de-registered and not even a factor in the further performance of the page.   What gives? **

Comment: wich version of angular do you use?

Comment: 1.2.22 and I am referring to it via the Google CDN

Comment: ok, the one time binding syntax is only available since 1.3.0. For older versions you have to use the **bindonce** plugin.

Comment: AHHH!!  You've got to be kidding me!  haha, okay, that is one problem solved ;-p  Thanks!  I needed version 1.30 (the latest build) as this is a newer feature.